# How to adjust the login pages with bootstrap?

Tags: theming

Components used:

- Bootstrap 3.7.1.
- Drupal 8

I would like to adjust the size of the login screen (and related screens) to a size of 6 grids. So I think adding the following bootstrap class

```
col-md-6 offset-md-3
```

to

```
.block-user-login-block
```

will do the trick. I can add this to the block css.

But bootstrap needs to have .row class just before this. How can I easily solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the bootstrap class to

col-md-6 col-md-offset-3